# Move ether between accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

Friends. I'm trying to learn. 
Thank you for your patience with my English.

Is it possible to move ether between my accounts without paying the transfer fee?

For exmaple, move 1.5 ETH from `eth.account[0]` to `eth.account[1]`.

without paying the transfer fee ?

Comment: moving ethers implies paying fees.

Comment: I did not understand
transaction fee obligation

Comment: You can't sweep accounts like you can in Bitcoin, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that without fees.

The "fact" of the transaction only takes shape when the rest of the network agrees that it actually happened. That is, it must be witnessed by the rest of the network or else it didn't happen.

Although you know that you are the owner of both accounts, the rest of the network is not aware of this and thus it must be treated as a regular transaction. The transaction fee is the price you pay for the network to ensure that the transaction really did take place.

Hope it helps.